# Cannot seem to import SequentialTaskSet

Tags: python, locust

I'm working on my LocustFile and discovered SequentialTaskSet, but when I try to import it as I see countless times in examples and documentation, I get an error:

`lmint/ERROR/stderr: cannot import name 'SequentialTaskSet' from 'locust' (/home/cameron/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/__init__.py)`

my python version is 3.7.5, locust 2.22.0 . What can I do to debug this issue? I cannot accomplish what I need to do without sequential tasks.

EDIT: The Locustfile and overall project can be viewed on github [here](https://github.com/starling-foundries/Treezy/blob/develop/src/tests/locustfile.py)

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment from @cyberwiz, I was using an ancient version of locust resulting from installing locustio from pypi instead of locust. Upgrading it did allow me to import SequentialTaskSet, so I am closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

No Locust version with the version number `2.22.0` exists. What does it say if you run `locust --version`?

Make sure that you've installed the `locust` PyPI package, and not the `locustio` package (which was used for 0.x versions of Locust and doesn't have `SequentialTaskSet`).

Comment: Hey, you're right I don't know where I got that version. The output is: locust 0.14.5
. I'll also edit the question with the git repo link for easier contextualization.

Comment: SequentialTaskSet was added in 1.0.